# Text-based slides (in order to support version control)

Tags: windows, presentation

Does anyone know a tool for Windows to make "textual" presentations?

I want to make it easy for people to contribute to the presentation.
"What you see is what you mean".

Here is the idea :

```
<slide><h1>Unicorns</h1><img ...>...</slide>
```

Answer (score 3):

**(1)** Not trendy, in fact somewhat old, but also reliable (and I have used it) is **[Slidy2](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Slidy_Help)** (and see the [demo](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/)). It is actually easier to use that it might first appear. It is fairly versatile, and *works*.

**(2)** What you describe is pretty much what **[Marp](https://yhatt.github.io/marp/)** is -- although from the [Github README](https://github.com/yhatt/marp/#marp), it seems to have been mothballed (although there have been some very recent commits). I've never used it.

**(3)** Another Markdown option (and possibly abandoned?) is **[remark](https://github.com/gnab/remark#remark)**, although the [online demo](https://remarkjs.com/#1) looks fairly impressive. (Not one I've used myself.)

**(4)** trikita's **[slide-html](https://github.com/trikita/slide-html)** looks quite basic, but with impressive results. It does claim to be "The most simple plain text presentation maker", though! (Again, I've not used it.) There's a link to an [online demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/trikita/slide-html/blob/master/slide.html) in the README.

---

I should also add that **Pandoc + Markdown** gives options for [output to several browser-based presentation formats](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc) -- it's worth looking into those, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can have this effect using LaTeX. Whole document is saved in text and you can generate presentations from LateX sources.

Another option is to use knitr. It's able to generate presentations from text and data. It's usually used to present data and graphs, but can be used for another applications. If that'll work for you, you should check RStudio - has nice support for knitr and RMarkdown (syntax used in script). It may require some code (not necesarrly), but if you don't want to write any code first check LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I use [hovercraft](https://github.com/regebro/hovercraft) which turns markdown into HTML slides with some nice effects. It's based on impress.js underneath.